# Allow Only Checkboxes in same div to be Checked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I have 3 Divs, every div contains 2 inputs, I want to only check checkboxes in the same div with id and unchecked from other divs.

HTML is :

```
<div class="dashboard">

 <div id="fr">
  <h3>Fruits</h3>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Kiwi</label>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Jackfruit</label>
 </div>

 <div id="an">
  <h3>Animals</h3>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>
 </div>

 <div id="veg">
  <h3>vegetables</h3>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>
 </div>

</div>
```

and JQuery is :

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
 var $box = $(this);
 if ($box.is(":checked")) {
  var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
  $(group).prop("checked", false);
  $box.prop("checked", true);
 } else {
 $box.prop("checked", false);
 }
});
```

see [live example](https://codepen.io/yousefmohamed/pen/ExvbwXJ)

Comment: So, you want radio buttons? https://jsfiddle.net/d85nxcgh/ or https://jsfiddle.net/d85nxcgh/1/

Comment: a radio button is useful, but I want to be able to check checkboxes in the same div and uncheck all checkboxes in other divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to allow checkboxes to be checked within a single `div`, you can use jQuery to traverse the DOM using `closest()`, `siblings()` and `find()` to retrieve the external checkboxes before de-selecting them.

Try this:

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('change', e => {
  $(e.target).closest('div').siblings().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard">
  <div id="fr">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Kiwi</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Jackfruit</label>
  </div>
  <div id="an">
    <h3>Animals</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>
  </div>
  <div id="veg">
    <h3>vegetables</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is totally true.