# show alert when checkboxes siblings are changed to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, alert

I have 3 divs, every div contains 2 checkboxes, and when I check any of the checkboxes in the same div no problem, but when I check the checkboxes in different div the other checkboxes are unchecked.

See [live example](https://codepen.io/yousefmohamed/pen/bGrKJoL) or the Stack Snippet below to understand better.

I need to show an alert when checking checkboxes in other divs that show a message "your selected items will be unchecked".

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('change', e => {
  $(e.target).closest('div').siblings().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  alert("your selected items will be unchecked");
});
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div id="fr">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Kiwi</label>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Jackfruit</label>

  </div>
  <div id="an">
    <h3>Animals</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>

  </div>

  <div id="veg">
    <h3>vegetables</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Broccoli</label>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Carrots</label>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! *"see live example for more understand."* Please put your live example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Off-site resources are blocked for some people, links rot over time, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. **Edit:** The code in the question *seems* to replicate what you describe, so I've copied it into a Stack Snippet for you. (I didn't look at the linked example, though, so you may still need to edit it.)

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem, just put `alert('your selected items will be unchecked');` before or after jquery siblings code or if you want use only jquery use Jquery UI with dialog.

Comment: *"I need to show an alert when checking checkboxes in other divs that show a message "your selected items will be unchecked"."* I don't see anything in the code in the question that tries to do that...?

Comment: I think you looking for solution to being unchecked in other divs, isn't it?

Comment: This is a *follow on* question from OPs [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882851/allow-only-checkboxes-in-same-div-to-be-checked-using-jquery) - the functionality isn't at question, just adding an "alert".

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes it is

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code that unchecks your other checkboxes to see if any will be unchecked:

```
$(e.target).closest('div').siblings().find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0
```

Using a variable to reduce the amount of DOM navigation gives:

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('change', e => {
  var otherCheckboxes = $(e.target).closest('div').siblings().find("input:checkbox")
  if (otherCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0)
      alert("Your other options will be removed.");
  otherCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div id="fr">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Kiwi</label>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Jackfruit</label>

  </div>
  <div id="an">
    <h3>Animals</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>

  </div>

  <div id="veg">
    <h3>vegetables</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Broccoli</label>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Carrots</label>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

The UX could be improved by using `confirm` instead of an `alert` (or a proper UI dialog of course)

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', e => {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
    return; 
  var otherCheckboxes = $(e.target).closest('div').siblings().find("input:checkbox")
  if (otherCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0) {
      if (confirm("Your other options will be removed.  Continue?")) {
          otherCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div id="fr">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Kiwi</label>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Jackfruit</label>

  </div>
  <div id="an">
    <h3>Animals</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Tiger</label>
    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Sloth</label>

  </div>

  <div id="veg">
    <h3>vegetables</h3>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />Broccoli</label>
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />Carrots</label>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```